# main.c cannot read functions that i declare in .h file and define in another .c file (in C)

Tags: c, codeblocks, linker-errors

recently I was trying to understand the usage of extern and creating my own header file in c. I wrote a simple program that swaps the values of numbers and shows them. Of course i know that i can do that in a more simple way but I have that problem with my code. I wrote in a same project main.c, header.c, header.h.

MAIN.c is that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

   int x,y;
  int main()
   {

 x = 3;
 y = 4;
 swap();
 show(x,y);
 return 0;


 }
```

Header.c is that:

```
    #include "header.h"

     void swap(){
     const int hilf = x;
     x=y;
    y=hilf;
    }

        void show (int i,int j)
    {
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
    swap();
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);


    }
```

and the Header File is that :

```
        #ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
        #define HEADER_H_INCLUDED
        #include <stdio.h>
        extern int x,y;
        extern void swap(void);
        extern void show(int,int y);

        #endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

im getting that error in main function:
"undefined reference to'swap'"
"undefined reference to'show'"

What should I do to fix the code or where my mistake ?

Im waiting for your answers..

Comment: You don't build with both source files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you maybe write more specific ?

Comment: *How* do you build? Using an IDE? Direct on the command line? Please tell us, and if you build on the command line then please show us the commands you use. And if you're using an IDE then what files are listed inside the project tree in the IDE?

Comment: do you do `gcc main.c header.c` or just `gcc main.c` ? (whatever it is gcc or an other compiler)

Comment: im using CodeBlocks and my compiler is gnu gcc

Comment: Do you also have the error concerning _show_ like in my answer ?

Comment: no i have just the things that i wrote in my build messages and that error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Add the complete build log to your question (copy & paste it directly), not just the error message.  It will show how the project was compiled and linked.  Chances are that you have simply not added `header.c` to your project in the IDE.

Comment: Your problem is your build system. I edited the tags to clarify that (feel free to re-edit/roll back if you think I got it wrong). I don't know CodeBlocks build system, but you gotta make it understand you have several source files in your project, so it can link them all together when creating the executable.

Comment: -------------- Build: Debug in Deneme (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\trial.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/bb/Documents/trial/main.c:11: undefined reference to `swap'
C:/Users/bb/Documents/trial/main.c:12: undefined reference to `show'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: my build log is like that i think it cannot see my header file or am i getting it wrong ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a3NUrsc And thats the Project Tree

Comment: @BBprog you also have the error concerning _show_. I edited my answer please refer to it

Comment: regarding: `#include <stdio.h>` in the `header.h` file,  Only include headers when they are needed.  `stdio.h` is not needed in the `header.h` file because nothing in the `header.h` file is using anything from `stdio.h`

Answer (score 3):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ gcc main.c  
/tmp/ccmKPwcW.o : in the function « main » :
main.c:(.text+0x20) : undefined reference to « swap »
main.c:(.text+0x3c) : undefined reference to « show »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ gcc main.c  header.c 
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $
```

you missed to link with header.o

Of course can be through

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ gcc -c main.c 
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ gcc -c header.c 
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ gcc main.o
main.o : Ine the function « main » :
main.c:(.text+0x20) : undefined reference to « swap »
main.c:(.text+0x3c) : undefined reference to « show »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Edit after the remark of the OP

> -------------- Build: Debug in Deneme (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)--------------- mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Debug\trial.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\main.o: In function main':
>
> C:/Users/bb/Documents/trial/main.c:11: undefined reference to swap'
>
> C:/Users/bb/Documents/trial/main.c:12: undefined reference to `show'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

As you can see in `mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Debug\trial.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\main.o` you miss to link with *header.o* because you link two times *main.o*.

Must be `mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Debug\trial.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\header.o`

Additional remark : *header.** is a very strange name for a couple of files where one is not a header file

Comment: Might be nice to demonstrate `gcc main.o header.o`... and perhaps mention that `header.c` is a terrible name.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes to use _header.c_ is so strange

Comment: yes sorry about the name :) but how can i make it correct? I ve just created the header in project why did it happened ?

Comment: @BBprog The main problem is not the name but the fact you link two times with main as I say in my answer. I never used _CodeBlocks_, look how you indicate the files to compiler/link

Comment: @BBprog did you enter the list of the files or CodeBlocks works by itself on all the files ?

Comment: @bruno first i opened one project (so the main.c is automaticly openning) and then i add new file in to the project tree and i saved it into the project because main.c is also there and then i add a new header file  like that and i saved it in project also. CodeBlocks is a little bit simpeler that the other IDE's. That was also my first time tht i create my own Header file but i dont thing i did something wrong there i just followed the introductions.

Comment: @BBprog I never used CodeBlocks. May be save your files (in case), delete the project and re-create it then re-compile ?